# How to have nameless YAML fixtures in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

Let's say we have.

```
 apple:
    name: apple

  orange:
    name: orange

  grape:
    name: grape
```

Can this turn into something below?

```
    name: apple

    name: orange

    name: grape
```

Because I have like 25 items, manually name them is really a valueless job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, also because this is not a valid YML syntax.
Each fixture element must belong to a name which reflects the YAML node name.

However, you can generate the names with Ruby.

```
<% %w(apple orange grape).each do |fruit| %>
<%= fruit %>:
    name: <%= fruit %>
<% end %>
```